# .net CORE view model property of type object does not bind

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have an MVC web app that I am porting from .net framework to .net core. Part of the app has a view model with a number of properties, one of which is of type "object".

In .net framework when I post this view model data the controller receives it with no problem. However, in .net CORE all the properties contain their expected values except the one that is object.

If I change the type to string most work fine (but it means if the value is ever an int (for example) it will be the string representation of an int).

Does anybody know how I can get values for view model properties that are object types to work or if this just isn't supported in Core?

Comment: Hi, are you sure this was binding in your legacy mvc application?   the  model binder uses advanced reflection to determine how to map the request data into properties.  for a property of type "object" it cannot tell if this is a complex object like a Customer object or if it is a string or int and I dont see how it could map this correctly. I dont see any examples in legacy mvc mapping to a type of "object".  i feel like this would likely fail in asp.net mvc as well as core.

Comment: @Matt, that is not true, the default model binder supports conversion to most basic types with object e.g Bool, Int String.  (I don't think Date works but I haven't tried)

Comment: @Pseudo, I don't think core has support for that yet, you should write a custom binder which uses the json serializer to resolve to object

Comment: @johnny5 yes sir I agree. I think you are misreading my comment. I am just saying it does not support binding to type "object" because it cannot tell if it is a complex type or a simple type like int or string. i wrote the full answer below.  thanks

Comment: @Matt, thanks, I'm trying to clarify that the default model binder can bind to the type `Object`, but only for simple types (Int, string bool), it can figure it out from the json provided.

Comment: I wanted to setup to confirm. I set up a simple example in mvc using two test actions.
        public IActionResult About(object name)     
        public IActionResult About(string name)    In the string version i receive the name. In the object version i do not. The model binder is unable to bind to type of "object".  Here is another stackoverflow post to confirm as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005121/object-as-a-parameter-for-an-action-controller

Comment: @Matt, In .Net Core you need to make a custom model binder. When you're accepting json you can easily determine if something is an int, string or bool based on whether it has quotes or is a number.  the majoirity of the functionality is done for you by JsonDeserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont feel like this would work.

Model binding uses reflection to map request data, route data and query strings into the parameter of your action method.

Request data is essentially all string data and so the defaultmodelbinder is able to map the request into any simple value type such as  string, integer or bool by checking to see if the string can be converted into an int or bool without failure.

Complex types, like a Customer object, which contain simple value types (like string and int) can then also be mapped using this same methodology. An example of a complex type like this is shown here:

```
public class Customer
{
     public string Name {get;set} 
     public bool IsLongTermCustomer {get;set;}
}
```

Because the defaultmodelbinder uses reflection, I really dont see how it would know how to map to a property of type "object" which could be anything.

An object could be a Customer, an int ,a string etc and so i feel like this would fail no matter what version of MVC you use becaue i dont see how the defaultmodelbinder would know if the data can be ported into the object data type. Here is a detailed article on model binding specifically in MVC core and how it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

As an extra check, I would also look to see if you are running the mvc default model binder in your older application and that someone is not using a custom model binder which may be allowing this binding to occur in your legacy application.